# Editing SVG to change character

Tags: svg

I have an SVG, which displays alphabets using SVG (weird I know), now, whoever wrote it made a mistake in the spelling and now since editing it is not the same as simply backspacing the wrong one and typing in the right one.

The entire SVG can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vf87btk9/2/

The path for the wrong spelling is "#STRATRGY"

```
<path id="STRATRGY" class="smallcls-9" d="M1921.69,555.488a4.287,4.287,0,0,0-.71-2.592,4.721,4.721,0,0,0-1.72-1.5,17.728,17.728,0,0,0-2.63-1.02q-1.275-.432-2.01-0.756a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.21-.888,2.126,2.126,0,0,1-.48-1.428,2.076,2.076,0,0,1,.7-1.692,2.763,2.763,0,0,1,1.85-.588,2.825,2.825,0,0,1,2,.684,2.856,2.856,0,0,1,.9,1.644h2.95a4.673,4.673,0,0,0-1.74-3.264,6.289,6.289,0,0,0-4.11-1.248,6.916,6.916,0,0,0-2.88.564,4.214,4.214,0,0,0-2.6,4,4.224,4.224,0,0,0,.7,2.52,4.686,4.686,0,0,0,1.69,1.464,18.351,18.351,0,0,0,2.58,1.008,21.058,21.058,0,0,1,2.04.768,3.541,3.541,0,0,1,1.25.924,2.2,2.2,0,0,1,.5,1.5,2.3,2.3,0,0,1-.68,1.728,2.645,2.645,0,0,1-1.93.672,3.071,3.071,0,0,1-2.22-.792,3.016,3.016,0,0,1-.95-1.9h-2.93a4.825,4.825,0,0,0,.94,2.544,5.361,5.361,0,0,0,2.18,1.716,7.523,7.523,0,0,0,3.1.612,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,3-.648,4.387,4.387,0,0,0,1.82-1.716,4.65,4.65,0,0,0,.6-2.316h0Zm1.44-12.432v2.208h4.71V560h2.76V545.264h4.72v-2.208h-12.19ZM1949.34,560l-4.44-6.888a5.332,5.332,0,0,0,3.23-1.632,4.784,4.784,0,0,0,1.11-3.264,4.908,4.908,0,0,0-1.5-3.744,6.171,6.171,0,0,0-4.4-1.416h-5.98V560h2.74v-6.768h1.94l4.23,6.768h3.07Zm-9.24-14.592h3.02a3.479,3.479,0,0,1,2.51.78,2.874,2.874,0,0,1,.81,2.172q0,2.928-3.32,2.928h-3.02v-5.88ZM1963.12,560h2.92l-6.21-16.68h-3.15L1950.44,560h2.93l1.3-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.8-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.61Zm11.35-11.16v2.208h4.7V560h2.76V545.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19ZM1993,560l-4.44-6.888a5.3,5.3,0,0,0,3.22-1.632,4.741,4.741,0,0,0,1.12-3.264,4.908,4.908,0,0,0-1.5-3.744,6.187,6.187,0,0,0-4.4-1.416h-5.98V560h2.74v-6.768h1.94l4.22,6.768H1993Zm-9.24-14.592h3.02a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,2.51.78,2.907,2.907,0,0,1,.8,2.172q0,2.928-3.31,2.928h-3.02v-5.88Zm19.36-2.5a8.511,8.511,0,0,0-4.35,1.092,7.483,7.483,0,0,0-2.92,3.048,10.241,10.241,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.587,7.587,0,0,0,2.93,3.06,8.513,8.513,0,0,0,4.37,1.1,8.211,8.211,0,0,0,3.92-.912,7.515,7.515,0,0,0,2.76-2.436,8.03,8.03,0,0,0,1.33-3.4v-2.616h-8.52v2.016h6.22a5.586,5.586,0,0,1-1.82,3.588,5.369,5.369,0,0,1-3.63,1.308,6.09,6.09,0,0,1-3.03-.732,4.962,4.962,0,0,1-2.03-2.124,7.18,7.18,0,0,1-.72-3.336,6.81,6.81,0,0,1,.71-3.216,5.1,5.1,0,0,1,1.96-2.112,5.5,5.5,0,0,1,2.85-.744,5.387,5.387,0,0,1,2.99.816,4.607,4.607,0,0,1,1.81,2.184h2.88a6.968,6.968,0,0,0-2.67-4.056,8.24,8.24,0,0,0-5.04-1.488h0Zm20.48,0.144-3.89,7.848-3.89-7.848h-3.17l5.67,10.776V560h2.76v-6.168l5.64-10.776h-3.12Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
```

It is supposed to read "STRATEGY" but right now it is reading "STRATRGY".

I have tried using https://editor.method.ac/ to edit the SVG but when I paste the SVG code there it all seems broken. Any SVG expert who can help me out?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="55vh" viewBox="0 0 600 585">
<metadata>
 <!--?xpacket begin="&#65279;" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?-->
  <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c142 79.160924, 2017/07/13-01:06:39        ">
   <rdf:rdf xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:description rdf:about=""></rdf:description>
   </rdf:rdf>
  </x:xmpmeta>
 <!--?xpacket end="w"?-->
</metadata>
<defs>
 <style>
   .smallcls-1, .smallcls-2, .smallcls-3, .smallcls-4, .smallcls-5, .smallcls-6, .smallcls-7, .smallcls-8 {
  fill: #fff;
   }

   .smallcls-1, .smallcls-2, .smallcls-3, .smallcls-4, .smallcls-5, .smallcls-6, .smallcls-7, .smallcls-8, .smallcls-9 {
  fill-rule: evenodd;
   }

   .smallcls-2 {
  opacity: 0.8;
   }

   .smallcls-3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
   }

   .smallcls-4 {
  opacity: 0.6;
   }

   .smallcls-5 {
  opacity: 0.5;
   }

   .smallcls-6 {
  opacity: 0.3;
   }

   .smallcls-7 {
  opacity: 0.4;
   }

   .smallcls-8 {
  opacity: 0.35;
   }

   .smallcls-9 {
  fill: #1f1f1f;
   }
 </style>
</defs>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/content-factory/" id="Polygon_1" data-name="Polygon 1" class="smallcls-1 curPoint" d="M1559.88,307.924l-96.89-55.985V139.969l96.89-55.984,96.89,55.984v111.97Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/mobility-experience/" id="Polygon_1_copy" data-name="Polygon 1 copy" class="smallcls-2 curPoint" d="M1764.49,307.924l-96.89-55.985V139.969l96.89-55.984,96.89,55.984v111.97Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/product-information-mgmt/" id="Polygon_1_copy_2" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 2" class="smallcls-3 curPoint" d="M1968.1,307.924l-96.89-55.985V139.969l96.89-55.984,96.88,55.984v111.97Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/experience-design/" id="Polygon_1_copy_3" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 3" class="smallcls-4 curPoint" d="M1662.06,484.425l-96.89-55.985V316.47l96.89-55.985,96.89,55.985V428.44Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/product-ux/" id="Polygon_1_copy_3-2" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 3" class="smallcls-5 curPoint" d="M1865.67,484.425l-96.89-55.985V316.47l96.89-55.985,96.89,55.985V428.44Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/digital-commerce-strategy/" id="Polygon_1_copy_3-3" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 3" class="smallcls-6 curPoint" d="M1968.1,663l-96.89-55.985V495.04l96.89-55.984,96.88,55.984V607.01Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/technologies/" id="Polygon_1_copy_5" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 5" class="smallcls-7 curPoint" d="M1561.26,663l-96.89-55.985V495.04l96.89-55.984,96.89,55.984V607.01Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path data-url="https://codifydtest.com/analytics/" id="Polygon_1_copy_4" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 4" class="smallcls-8" d="M1763.87,663l-96.89-55.985V495.04l96.89-55.984,96.89,55.984V607.01Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="CONTENT_DATA" data-name="CONTENT  &amp; DATA" class="smallcls-9" d="M1513.66,172.888a8.088,8.088,0,0,0-4.24,1.1,7.421,7.421,0,0,0-2.86,3.06,10.423,10.423,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.343,7.343,0,0,0,2.86,3.048,8.157,8.157,0,0,0,4.24,1.092,8.335,8.335,0,0,0,5.19-1.572,7.707,7.707,0,0,0,2.78-4.284h-2.9a5.191,5.191,0,0,1-1.91,2.412,5.508,5.508,0,0,1-3.2.9,4.971,4.971,0,0,1-2.7-.744,5.1,5.1,0,0,1-1.88-2.124,7.945,7.945,0,0,1,0-6.432,5.1,5.1,0,0,1,1.88-2.124,4.971,4.971,0,0,1,2.7-.744,5.508,5.508,0,0,1,3.2.9,5.176,5.176,0,0,1,1.91,2.436h2.9a7.765,7.765,0,0,0-2.78-4.3,8.291,8.291,0,0,0-5.19-1.584h0Zm18.56-.048a8.4,8.4,0,0,0-4.29,1.1,8.011,8.011,0,0,0-3.01,3.084,9.657,9.657,0,0,0,0,8.952,8.1,8.1,0,0,0,3.01,3.1,8.746,8.746,0,0,0,8.55,0,8,8,0,0,0,3-3.1,9.735,9.735,0,0,0,0-8.952,7.917,7.917,0,0,0-3-3.084,8.393,8.393,0,0,0-4.26-1.1h0Zm0,2.544a5.509,5.509,0,0,1,2.86.744,5.087,5.087,0,0,1,1.97,2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0,6.48,5.087,5.087,0,0,1-1.97,2.136,5.509,5.509,0,0,1-2.86.744,5.666,5.666,0,0,1-2.91-.744,5.046,5.046,0,0,1-1.98-2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0-6.48,5.046,5.046,0,0,1,1.98-2.136,5.666,5.666,0,0,1,2.91-.744h0Zm24.81-2.3h-2.73v12.552l-8.24-12.552h-2.73V190h2.73V177.5l8.24,12.5h2.73V173.08Zm2.02-.024v2.208h4.7V190h2.76V175.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19Zm23.93,2.208v-2.208h-9.7V190h9.7v-2.232h-6.96v-5.256h6.24V180.4h-6.24v-5.136h6.96Zm16.36-2.184h-2.73v12.552l-8.23-12.552h-2.74V190h2.74V177.5l8.23,12.5h2.73V173.08Zm2.02-.024v2.208h4.7V190h2.76V175.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19ZM1535.8,218.8l-8.83-10.728a7.364,7.364,0,0,1-.78-1.128,2.37,2.37,0,0,1-.25-1.128,1.763,1.763,0,0,1,.52-1.3,1.892,1.892,0,0,1,1.42-.528,2.057,2.057,0,0,1,1.55.576,2.249,2.249,0,0,1,.59,1.584,3.631,3.631,0,0,1,.02.528v0.264h2.6a5.549,5.549,0,0,0-.17-1.7,4.393,4.393,0,0,0-1.41-2.544,4.645,4.645,0,0,0-3.22-1.008,5.141,5.141,0,0,0-2.44.54,3.8,3.8,0,0,0-1.54,1.428,3.746,3.746,0,0,0-.51,1.9,3.885,3.885,0,0,0,.31,1.6,6.369,6.369,0,0,0,.89,1.428l0.31,0.432h-0.17a4.422,4.422,0,0,0-2.23.576,4.174,4.174,0,0,0-1.6,1.68,5.513,5.513,0,0,0-.58,2.616,5.309,5.309,0,0,0,.64,2.64,4.62,4.62,0,0,0,1.83,1.8,5.544,5.544,0,0,0,2.73.648,4.44,4.44,0,0,0,2.66-.8,3.7,3.7,0,0,0,1.45-2.1,4.891,4.891,0,0,0,.24-0.84L1533,218.8h2.8Zm-10.29-2.16a2.9,2.9,0,0,1-2.03-.756,3.077,3.077,0,0,1-.11-4.08,2.564,2.564,0,0,1,1.87-.708,2.928,2.928,0,0,1,1.43.372,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,1.11,1.032,2.692,2.692,0,0,1,.42,1.476,2.6,2.6,0,0,1-.76,1.92,2.634,2.634,0,0,1-1.93.744h0Zm32.23-6.336a9.178,9.178,0,0,0-1.04-4.464,7.227,7.227,0,0,0-3.05-2.94,10.25,10.25,0,0,0-4.79-1.044h-5.66V218.8h5.66a10.153,10.153,0,0,0,4.79-1.056,7.281,7.281,0,0,0,3.05-2.964,9.249,9.249,0,0,0,1.04-4.476h0Zm-9.1,6.024h-2.71V204.28h2.71a6.423,6.423,0,0,1,4.68,1.584,6.83,6.83,0,0,1,0,8.88,6.423,6.423,0,0,1-4.68,1.584h0Zm23.26,2.472h2.93l-6.22-16.68h-3.14l-6.24,16.68h2.93l1.29-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.81-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.62Zm11.35-11.16v2.208h4.71V218.8h2.76V204.064h4.72v-2.208h-12.19ZM1601.2,218.8h2.93l-6.21-16.68h-3.15l-6.24,16.68h2.93l1.3-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.81-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.62Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="MOBILITY" class="smallcls-9" d="M1727.29,187.32l-5.42,13.32-5.52-13.32h-3.31V204h2.73V191.5l4.85,12.5h2.4l4.82-12.5V204h2.76V187.32h-3.31Zm14.45-.48a8.388,8.388,0,0,0-4.28,1.1,7.966,7.966,0,0,0-3.02,3.084,9.657,9.657,0,0,0,0,8.952,8.053,8.053,0,0,0,3.02,3.1,8.727,8.727,0,0,0,8.54,0,8,8,0,0,0,3-3.1,9.735,9.735,0,0,0,0-8.952,7.917,7.917,0,0,0-3-3.084,8.34,8.34,0,0,0-4.26-1.1h0Zm0,2.544a5.546,5.546,0,0,1,2.87.744,5.151,5.151,0,0,1,1.97,2.136,7.848,7.848,0,0,1,0,6.48,5.151,5.151,0,0,1-1.97,2.136,5.546,5.546,0,0,1-2.87.744,5.6,5.6,0,0,1-2.9-.744,5.046,5.046,0,0,1-1.98-2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0-6.48,5.046,5.046,0,0,1,1.98-2.136,5.6,5.6,0,0,1,2.9-.744h0Zm19.94,5.88a4.048,4.048,0,0,0,2.21-1.332,4.372,4.372,0,0,0-.51-5.736,5.928,5.928,0,0,0-3.9-1.14h-6.63V204h6.75a6.048,6.048,0,0,0,4.1-1.236,4.232,4.232,0,0,0,1.42-3.348,4.115,4.115,0,0,0-.95-2.688,4.185,4.185,0,0,0-2.49-1.464h0Zm-6.09-5.976h3.29a3.378,3.378,0,0,1,2.29.672,2.355,2.355,0,0,1,.75,1.848,2.384,2.384,0,0,1-.75,1.872,3.227,3.227,0,0,1-2.2.672h-3.38v-5.064Zm3.45,12.456h-3.45v-5.4h3.43a3.659,3.659,0,0,1,2.42.72,2.723,2.723,0,0,1,.02,3.972,3.7,3.7,0,0,1-2.42.708h0Zm8.64-14.688V204h2.74V187.056h-2.74Zm8.79,0h-2.74V204h8.59v-2.136h-5.85V187.056Zm7.99,0V204h2.74V187.056h-2.74Zm4.75,0v2.208h4.71V204h2.76V189.264h4.72v-2.208h-12.19Zm23.91,0-3.89,7.848-3.89-7.848h-3.17l5.67,10.776V204h2.76v-6.168l5.64-10.776h-3.12Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="PIM" class="smallcls-9" d="M1954.94,197.424a6.26,6.26,0,0,0,4.37-1.38,4.854,4.854,0,0,0,1.51-3.78,5,5,0,0,0-1.47-3.816,6.216,6.216,0,0,0-4.41-1.392h-5.76V204h2.74v-6.576h3.02Zm-0.28-2.232h-2.74v-5.88h2.74a3.7,3.7,0,0,1,2.58.756,2.89,2.89,0,0,1,.8,2.2q0,2.928-3.38,2.928h0Zm8.56-8.136V204h2.74V187.056h-2.74Zm20.31,0.264-5.43,13.32-5.52-13.32h-3.31V204h2.74V191.5l4.85,12.5h2.4l4.82-12.5V204h2.76V187.32h-3.31Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="TECHNOLOGY" class="smallcls-9" d="M1481.67,543.056v2.208h4.7V560h2.76V545.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19Zm23.93,2.208v-2.208h-9.7V560h9.7v-2.232h-6.96v-5.256h6.24V550.4h-6.24v-5.136h6.96Zm10.22-2.376a8.124,8.124,0,0,0-4.25,1.1,7.463,7.463,0,0,0-2.85,3.06,10.423,10.423,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.383,7.383,0,0,0,2.85,3.048,8.194,8.194,0,0,0,4.25,1.092,8.285,8.285,0,0,0,5.18-1.572,7.669,7.669,0,0,0,2.79-4.284h-2.91a5.171,5.171,0,0,1-1.9,2.412,5.54,5.54,0,0,1-3.21.9,4.971,4.971,0,0,1-2.7-.744,5.153,5.153,0,0,1-1.87-2.124,7.945,7.945,0,0,1,0-6.432,5.153,5.153,0,0,1,1.87-2.124,4.971,4.971,0,0,1,2.7-.744,5.54,5.54,0,0,1,3.21.9,5.157,5.157,0,0,1,1.9,2.436h2.91a7.727,7.727,0,0,0-2.79-4.3,8.242,8.242,0,0,0-5.18-1.584h0Zm21.41,0.168v7.1h-7.97v-7.1h-2.74V560h2.74v-7.608h7.97V560h2.76V543.056h-2.76ZM1557,543.08h-2.73v12.552l-8.23-12.552h-2.74V560h2.74V547.5l8.23,12.5H1557V543.08Zm11.16-.24a8.388,8.388,0,0,0-4.28,1.1,7.942,7.942,0,0,0-3.01,3.084,9.58,9.58,0,0,0,0,8.952,8.028,8.028,0,0,0,3.01,3.1,8.727,8.727,0,0,0,8.54,0,7.865,7.865,0,0,0,3-3.1,9.657,9.657,0,0,0,0-8.952,7.782,7.782,0,0,0-3-3.084,8.34,8.34,0,0,0-4.26-1.1h0Zm0,2.544a5.52,5.52,0,0,1,2.87.744,5.087,5.087,0,0,1,1.97,2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0,6.48,5.087,5.087,0,0,1-1.97,2.136,5.52,5.52,0,0,1-2.87.744,5.655,5.655,0,0,1-2.9-.744,5.046,5.046,0,0,1-1.98-2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0-6.48,5.046,5.046,0,0,1,1.98-2.136,5.655,5.655,0,0,1,2.9-.744h0Zm13.85-2.328h-2.73V560h8.59v-2.136h-5.86V543.056Zm15.84-.216a8.388,8.388,0,0,0-4.28,1.1,7.942,7.942,0,0,0-3.01,3.084,9.58,9.58,0,0,0,0,8.952,8.028,8.028,0,0,0,3.01,3.1,8.727,8.727,0,0,0,8.54,0,8,8,0,0,0,3-3.1,9.735,9.735,0,0,0,0-8.952,7.917,7.917,0,0,0-3-3.084,8.34,8.34,0,0,0-4.26-1.1h0Zm0,2.544a5.546,5.546,0,0,1,2.87.744,5.087,5.087,0,0,1,1.97,2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0,6.48,5.087,5.087,0,0,1-1.97,2.136,5.546,5.546,0,0,1-2.87.744,5.629,5.629,0,0,1-2.9-.744,5.046,5.046,0,0,1-1.98-2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0-6.48,5.046,5.046,0,0,1,1.98-2.136,5.629,5.629,0,0,1,2.9-.744h0Zm18.87-2.472a8.549,8.549,0,0,0-4.36,1.092,7.483,7.483,0,0,0-2.92,3.048,10.241,10.241,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.587,7.587,0,0,0,2.93,3.06,8.538,8.538,0,0,0,4.37,1.1,8.211,8.211,0,0,0,3.92-.912,7.515,7.515,0,0,0,2.76-2.436,8.177,8.177,0,0,0,1.34-3.4v-2.616h-8.52v2.016h6.21a5.541,5.541,0,0,1-1.82,3.588,5.369,5.369,0,0,1-3.63,1.308,6.09,6.09,0,0,1-3.03-.732,5.02,5.02,0,0,1-2.03-2.124,7.18,7.18,0,0,1-.72-3.336,6.932,6.932,0,0,1,.71-3.216,5.119,5.119,0,0,1,1.97-2.112,5.462,5.462,0,0,1,2.84-.744,5.387,5.387,0,0,1,2.99.816,4.607,4.607,0,0,1,1.81,2.184h2.88a7,7,0,0,0-2.66-4.056,8.281,8.281,0,0,0-5.04-1.488h0Zm20.47,0.144-3.89,7.848-3.89-7.848h-3.17l5.67,10.776V560h2.76v-6.168l5.64-10.776h-3.12Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="ANALYTICS" class="smallcls-9" d="M1713.84,560h2.93l-6.22-16.68h-3.14L1701.17,560h2.93l1.29-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.81-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.62Zm26.35-11.136h-2.73v12.552l-8.24-12.552h-2.73V560h2.73V547.5l8.24,12.5h2.73V543.08ZM1747.22,560h2.93l-6.21-16.68h-3.15L1734.55,560h2.93l1.3-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.81-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.62Zm15.39-11.16h-2.74V560h8.59v-2.136h-5.85V543.056Zm17.66,0-3.89,7.848-3.88-7.848h-3.17l5.66,10.776V560h2.76v-6.168l5.64-10.776h-3.12Zm3.87,0v2.208h4.7V560h2.76V545.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19Zm14.23,0V560h2.73V543.056h-2.73Zm13.61-.168a8.124,8.124,0,0,0-4.25,1.1,7.487,7.487,0,0,0-2.86,3.06,10.423,10.423,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.407,7.407,0,0,0,2.86,3.048,8.194,8.194,0,0,0,4.25,1.092,8.305,8.305,0,0,0,5.18-1.572,7.655,7.655,0,0,0,2.78-4.284h-2.9a5.191,5.191,0,0,1-1.91,2.412,5.508,5.508,0,0,1-3.2.9,4.971,4.971,0,0,1-2.7-.744,5.084,5.084,0,0,1-1.87-2.124,7.84,7.84,0,0,1,0-6.432,5.084,5.084,0,0,1,1.87-2.124,4.971,4.971,0,0,1,2.7-.744,5.508,5.508,0,0,1,3.2.9,5.176,5.176,0,0,1,1.91,2.436h2.9a7.713,7.713,0,0,0-2.78-4.3,8.262,8.262,0,0,0-5.18-1.584h0Zm21.84,12.6a4.356,4.356,0,0,0-.71-2.592,4.751,4.751,0,0,0-1.73-1.5,17.728,17.728,0,0,0-2.63-1.02c-0.85-.288-1.51-0.54-2-0.756a3.312,3.312,0,0,1-1.21-.888,2.126,2.126,0,0,1-.48-1.428,2.1,2.1,0,0,1,.69-1.692,3.236,3.236,0,0,1,3.85.1,2.856,2.856,0,0,1,.9,1.644h2.96a4.749,4.749,0,0,0-1.74-3.264,6.318,6.318,0,0,0-4.12-1.248,6.916,6.916,0,0,0-2.88.564,4.391,4.391,0,0,0-1.92,1.6,4.282,4.282,0,0,0-.67,2.4,4.223,4.223,0,0,0,.69,2.52,4.716,4.716,0,0,0,1.7,1.464,17.419,17.419,0,0,0,2.58,1.008q1.29,0.432,2.04.768a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,1.24.924,2.207,2.207,0,0,1,.51,1.5,2.307,2.307,0,0,1-.69,1.728,2.629,2.629,0,0,1-1.93.672,3.071,3.071,0,0,1-2.22-.792,3.016,3.016,0,0,1-.95-1.9h-2.92a4.9,4.9,0,0,0,.93,2.544,5.393,5.393,0,0,0,2.19,1.716,7.476,7.476,0,0,0,3.09.612,6.315,6.315,0,0,0,3-.648,4.355,4.355,0,0,0,1.83-1.716,4.65,4.65,0,0,0,.6-2.316h0Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="STRATRGY" class="smallcls-9" d="M1921.69,555.488a4.287,4.287,0,0,0-.71-2.592,4.721,4.721,0,0,0-1.72-1.5,17.728,17.728,0,0,0-2.63-1.02q-1.275-.432-2.01-0.756a3.4,3.4,0,0,1-1.21-.888,2.126,2.126,0,0,1-.48-1.428,2.076,2.076,0,0,1,.7-1.692,2.763,2.763,0,0,1,1.85-.588,2.825,2.825,0,0,1,2,.684,2.856,2.856,0,0,1,.9,1.644h2.95a4.673,4.673,0,0,0-1.74-3.264,6.289,6.289,0,0,0-4.11-1.248,6.916,6.916,0,0,0-2.88.564,4.214,4.214,0,0,0-2.6,4,4.224,4.224,0,0,0,.7,2.52,4.686,4.686,0,0,0,1.69,1.464,18.351,18.351,0,0,0,2.58,1.008,21.058,21.058,0,0,1,2.04.768,3.541,3.541,0,0,1,1.25.924,2.2,2.2,0,0,1,.5,1.5,2.3,2.3,0,0,1-.68,1.728,2.645,2.645,0,0,1-1.93.672,3.071,3.071,0,0,1-2.22-.792,3.016,3.016,0,0,1-.95-1.9h-2.93a4.825,4.825,0,0,0,.94,2.544,5.361,5.361,0,0,0,2.18,1.716,7.523,7.523,0,0,0,3.1.612,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,3-.648,4.387,4.387,0,0,0,1.82-1.716,4.65,4.65,0,0,0,.6-2.316h0Zm1.44-12.432v2.208h4.71V560h2.76V545.264h4.72v-2.208h-12.19ZM1949.34,560l-4.44-6.888a5.332,5.332,0,0,0,3.23-1.632,4.784,4.784,0,0,0,1.11-3.264,4.908,4.908,0,0,0-1.5-3.744,6.171,6.171,0,0,0-4.4-1.416h-5.98V560h2.74v-6.768h1.94l4.23,6.768h3.07Zm-9.24-14.592h3.02a3.479,3.479,0,0,1,2.51.78,2.874,2.874,0,0,1,.81,2.172q0,2.928-3.32,2.928h-3.02v-5.88ZM1963.12,560h2.92l-6.21-16.68h-3.15L1950.44,560h2.93l1.3-3.672h7.15Zm-7.68-5.784,2.8-7.92,2.81,7.92h-5.61Zm11.35-11.16v2.208h4.7V560h2.76V545.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.19ZM1993,560l-4.44-6.888a5.3,5.3,0,0,0,3.22-1.632,4.741,4.741,0,0,0,1.12-3.264,4.908,4.908,0,0,0-1.5-3.744,6.187,6.187,0,0,0-4.4-1.416h-5.98V560h2.74v-6.768h1.94l4.22,6.768H1993Zm-9.24-14.592h3.02a3.5,3.5,0,0,1,2.51.78,2.907,2.907,0,0,1,.8,2.172q0,2.928-3.31,2.928h-3.02v-5.88Zm19.36-2.5a8.511,8.511,0,0,0-4.35,1.092,7.483,7.483,0,0,0-2.92,3.048,10.241,10.241,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.587,7.587,0,0,0,2.93,3.06,8.513,8.513,0,0,0,4.37,1.1,8.211,8.211,0,0,0,3.92-.912,7.515,7.515,0,0,0,2.76-2.436,8.03,8.03,0,0,0,1.33-3.4v-2.616h-8.52v2.016h6.22a5.586,5.586,0,0,1-1.82,3.588,5.369,5.369,0,0,1-3.63,1.308,6.09,6.09,0,0,1-3.03-.732,4.962,4.962,0,0,1-2.03-2.124,7.18,7.18,0,0,1-.72-3.336,6.81,6.81,0,0,1,.71-3.216,5.1,5.1,0,0,1,1.96-2.112,5.5,5.5,0,0,1,2.85-.744,5.387,5.387,0,0,1,2.99.816,4.607,4.607,0,0,1,1.81,2.184h2.88a6.968,6.968,0,0,0-2.67-4.056,8.24,8.24,0,0,0-5.04-1.488h0Zm20.48,0.144-3.89,7.848-3.89-7.848h-3.17l5.67,10.776V560h2.76v-6.168l5.64-10.776h-3.12Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="CX_DESIGN" data-name="CX DESIGN" class="smallcls-9" d="M1654.6,349.888a8.124,8.124,0,0,0-4.25,1.1,7.487,7.487,0,0,0-2.86,3.06,10.423,10.423,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.407,7.407,0,0,0,2.86,3.048,8.194,8.194,0,0,0,4.25,1.092,8.305,8.305,0,0,0,5.18-1.572,7.655,7.655,0,0,0,2.78-4.284h-2.9a5.191,5.191,0,0,1-1.91,2.412,5.508,5.508,0,0,1-3.2.9,4.971,4.971,0,0,1-2.7-.744,5.084,5.084,0,0,1-1.87-2.124,7.84,7.84,0,0,1,0-6.432,5.084,5.084,0,0,1,1.87-2.124,4.971,4.971,0,0,1,2.7-.744,5.508,5.508,0,0,1,3.2.9,5.176,5.176,0,0,1,1.91,2.436h2.9a7.713,7.713,0,0,0-2.78-4.3,8.262,8.262,0,0,0-5.18-1.584h0ZM1678.24,367l-5.45-8.448,5.23-8.5h-3.14l-3.6,6.144-3.99-6.144h-3.26l5.37,8.3-5.25,8.64h3.14l3.63-6.264,4.05,6.264h3.27Zm-42.62,20.3a9.068,9.068,0,0,0-1.04-4.464,7.171,7.171,0,0,0-3.05-2.94,10.221,10.221,0,0,0-4.79-1.044h-5.66V395.8h5.66a10.125,10.125,0,0,0,4.79-1.056,7.224,7.224,0,0,0,3.05-2.964,9.137,9.137,0,0,0,1.04-4.476h0Zm-9.09,6.024h-2.71V381.28h2.71a6.455,6.455,0,0,1,4.68,1.584,6.862,6.862,0,0,1,0,8.88,6.455,6.455,0,0,1-4.68,1.584h0Zm21.55-12.264v-2.208h-9.7V395.8h9.7v-2.232h-6.96v-5.256h6.24V386.2h-6.24v-5.136h6.96Zm13.8,10.224a4.356,4.356,0,0,0-.71-2.592,4.751,4.751,0,0,0-1.73-1.5,17.556,17.556,0,0,0-2.62-1.02q-1.275-.432-2.01-0.756a3.312,3.312,0,0,1-1.21-.888,2.126,2.126,0,0,1-.48-1.428,2.076,2.076,0,0,1,.7-1.692,2.753,2.753,0,0,1,1.84-.588,2.758,2.758,0,0,1,2.91,2.328h2.95a4.673,4.673,0,0,0-1.74-3.264,6.318,6.318,0,0,0-4.12-1.248,6.982,6.982,0,0,0-2.88.564,4.186,4.186,0,0,0-2.59,4,4.156,4.156,0,0,0,.7,2.52,4.686,4.686,0,0,0,1.69,1.464,17.419,17.419,0,0,0,2.58,1.008q1.29,0.432,2.04.768a3.541,3.541,0,0,1,1.25.924,2.252,2.252,0,0,1,.5,1.5,2.337,2.337,0,0,1-.68,1.728,2.645,2.645,0,0,1-1.93.672,3.071,3.071,0,0,1-2.22-.792,2.968,2.968,0,0,1-.95-1.9h-2.93a4.825,4.825,0,0,0,.94,2.544,5.361,5.361,0,0,0,2.18,1.716,7.49,7.49,0,0,0,3.1.612,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,3-.648,4.387,4.387,0,0,0,1.82-1.716,4.65,4.65,0,0,0,.6-2.316h0Zm2.74-12.432V395.8h2.73V378.856h-2.73Zm13.8-.144a8.549,8.549,0,0,0-4.36,1.092,7.483,7.483,0,0,0-2.92,3.048,10.241,10.241,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.587,7.587,0,0,0,2.93,3.06,8.538,8.538,0,0,0,4.37,1.1,8.211,8.211,0,0,0,3.92-.912,7.515,7.515,0,0,0,2.76-2.436,8.177,8.177,0,0,0,1.34-3.4v-2.616h-8.52v2.016h6.21a5.541,5.541,0,0,1-1.82,3.588,5.369,5.369,0,0,1-3.63,1.308,6.09,6.09,0,0,1-3.03-.732,5.02,5.02,0,0,1-2.03-2.124,7.18,7.18,0,0,1-.72-3.336,6.932,6.932,0,0,1,.71-3.216A5.119,5.119,0,0,1,1675.6,382a5.462,5.462,0,0,1,2.84-.744,5.387,5.387,0,0,1,2.99.816,4.607,4.607,0,0,1,1.81,2.184h2.88a7,7,0,0,0-2.66-4.056,8.281,8.281,0,0,0-5.04-1.488h0Zm24.5,0.168h-2.74v12.552l-8.23-12.552h-2.73V395.8h2.73V383.3l8.23,12.5h2.74V378.88Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
<path id="PRODUCT_UX" data-name="PRODUCT UX" class="smallcls-9" d="M1816.44,360.424a6.233,6.233,0,0,0,4.36-1.38,4.861,4.861,0,0,0,1.52-3.78,5.009,5.009,0,0,0-1.48-3.816,6.189,6.189,0,0,0-4.4-1.392h-5.76V367h2.73v-6.576h3.03Zm-0.29-2.232h-2.74v-5.88h2.74a3.7,3.7,0,0,1,2.58.756,2.89,2.89,0,0,1,.8,2.2q0,2.928-3.38,2.928h0ZM1836.69,367l-4.44-6.888a5.3,5.3,0,0,0,3.23-1.632,4.79,4.79,0,0,0,1.12-3.264,4.908,4.908,0,0,0-1.5-3.744,6.2,6.2,0,0,0-4.41-1.416h-5.97V367h2.73v-6.768h1.95l4.22,6.768h3.07Zm-9.24-14.592h3.03a3.468,3.468,0,0,1,2.5.78,2.874,2.874,0,0,1,.81,2.172c0,1.952-1.11,2.928-3.31,2.928h-3.03v-5.88Zm19.47-2.568a8.4,8.4,0,0,0-4.29,1.1,8.011,8.011,0,0,0-3.01,3.084,9.657,9.657,0,0,0,0,8.952,8.1,8.1,0,0,0,3.01,3.1,8.746,8.746,0,0,0,8.55,0,8,8,0,0,0,3-3.1,9.735,9.735,0,0,0,0-8.952,7.917,7.917,0,0,0-3-3.084,8.393,8.393,0,0,0-4.26-1.1h0Zm0,2.544a5.509,5.509,0,0,1,2.86.744,5.087,5.087,0,0,1,1.97,2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0,6.48,5.087,5.087,0,0,1-1.97,2.136,5.509,5.509,0,0,1-2.86.744,5.666,5.666,0,0,1-2.91-.744,5.046,5.046,0,0,1-1.98-2.136,7.748,7.748,0,0,1,0-6.48,5.046,5.046,0,0,1,1.98-2.136,5.666,5.666,0,0,1,2.91-.744h0Zm25.65,6.12a9.178,9.178,0,0,0-1.04-4.464,7.171,7.171,0,0,0-3.05-2.94,10.25,10.25,0,0,0-4.79-1.044h-5.66V367h5.66a10.153,10.153,0,0,0,4.79-1.056,7.224,7.224,0,0,0,3.05-2.964,9.249,9.249,0,0,0,1.04-4.476h0Zm-9.09,6.024h-2.72V352.48h2.72a6.455,6.455,0,0,1,4.68,1.584,6.862,6.862,0,0,1,0,8.88,6.455,6.455,0,0,1-4.68,1.584h0Zm11.73-14.472v10.056a7.149,7.149,0,0,0,1.78,5.268,6.323,6.323,0,0,0,4.7,1.788,6.44,6.44,0,0,0,4.75-1.788,7.114,7.114,0,0,0,1.8-5.268V350.056h-2.73v10.056a4.858,4.858,0,0,1-1,3.36,3.538,3.538,0,0,1-2.77,1.1,3.59,3.59,0,0,1-2.8-1.1,4.908,4.908,0,0,1-.99-3.36V350.056h-2.74Zm23.79-.168a8.124,8.124,0,0,0-4.25,1.1,7.487,7.487,0,0,0-2.86,3.06,10.423,10.423,0,0,0,0,8.952,7.407,7.407,0,0,0,2.86,3.048,8.194,8.194,0,0,0,4.25,1.092,8.305,8.305,0,0,0,5.18-1.572,7.655,7.655,0,0,0,2.78-4.284h-2.9a5.191,5.191,0,0,1-1.91,2.412,5.508,5.508,0,0,1-3.2.9,4.971,4.971,0,0,1-2.7-.744,5.084,5.084,0,0,1-1.87-2.124,7.84,7.84,0,0,1,0-6.432,5.084,5.084,0,0,1,1.87-2.124,4.971,4.971,0,0,1,2.7-.744,5.508,5.508,0,0,1,3.2.9,5.176,5.176,0,0,1,1.91,2.436h2.9a7.713,7.713,0,0,0-2.78-4.3,8.262,8.262,0,0,0-5.18-1.584h0Zm9.4,0.168v2.208h4.71V367h2.76V352.264h4.73v-2.208h-12.2Zm-57.4,28.8v10.056a7.187,7.187,0,0,0,1.77,5.268,6.346,6.346,0,0,0,4.71,1.788,6.456,6.456,0,0,0,4.75-1.788,7.114,7.114,0,0,0,1.8-5.268V378.856h-2.74v10.056a4.908,4.908,0,0,1-.99,3.36,4.065,4.065,0,0,1-5.57,0,4.858,4.858,0,0,1-1-3.36V378.856H1851Zm29.16,16.944-5.45-8.448,5.23-8.5h-3.14L1873.2,385l-3.99-6.144h-3.26l5.37,8.3-5.25,8.64h3.14l3.63-6.264,4.05,6.264h3.27Z" transform="translate(-1464 -81)"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape and start again from scratch.

Comment: @RobertLongson harshly said, but unfortunately true. While it is possible to edit this SVG to correct it, that requires considerable exierience, and even then the amount of work surpasses what it would take to make a new one. - The reason behind this is that someone converted the text parts, which normally would be as easy to edit as in HTML, to their grafical outline. That is an irreversible process.